# Azure Functions, Function key disappearing after a couple of days

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have a production function already running for a couple of months, on October the 6th it stopped working due to authentication problems (for some reason the default function key had changed). After adding the old function key again problems were resolved. However, I don't remember anymore if I added it as a function key or as host key. 
Now this night (23 October), the same problem occured, I had to enter the key again.Now I added the key both as a function and host key hoping to avoid more downtime.

I'm 100% sure that I didn't revoke or regenerated any keys (as I know you have to confirm this), but I recall that I yesterday opended the function in the portal.

Might this be some kind of bug? Is there a change that the keys get regenerated by something else? Is there some kind of auditing for this?

Comment: Did you by any chance deploy a new version of the functions? And if so: how did you deploy?

Comment: Can you share your function app name either directly or indirectly (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately) so we can take a closer look?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante: 2017-10-25T06:04:51.858 Function started (Id=81f1d30e-d0f7-4e9b-8678-dfd29239477e)

Comment: @BrechtVancauwenberghe we have identified and repaired an issue that was causing some sites to regenerate API keys. Are you still experiencing this problem?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante thanks, no, problem has not occurred anymore

Comment: @FabioCavalcante, I am facing the same problem. Does function keys get regenerated every-time it gets deployed? We are still in QA environment and I noticed it stopped working after deployment. Once I updated the key it was all working fine.